Test words in free profinite groups
Let $G$ be a group. An element $g \in G$ is said to be a test element if any endomorphism $\phi$ of $G$ such that $\phi(g) = g$ is an automorphism. The free group $F_2$ of rank $2$ is generated by $x_1$ and $x_2$. The natural identification of $F_2$ inside its pro-p completion or profinite completion is being used.
In the paper titled "Test Elements in Pro-p Groups" by Snopce and Tanuveshki, in Lemma 7.6, it is proved that $w$ is a test word in free group $F_2$ if and only if $w$ is a test word in a pro-p completion $(F_2)_p$ of $F_2$ for some prime $p$. The idea of the proof (if I am not wrong) is the following:
Turner has already classified test words in $F_2$ completely, i.e. $w \in F_2 \setminus \{e\}$ is a test word if and only if the $gcd$ of sum of exponents of $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $u$ is not $1$, where $w = u^n$ and $u$ is a non power word. Similarly, they proved that $w \in (F_2)_p \setminus \{e\}$ which is not a $p$-power element, is a  test word if and only if sum of exponents of $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $w$ both lies in $p\mathbb{Z}_p$, where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is pro-p completion of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then they showed $w \in F_2$ is a test word then there exists a prime $p$ which divides the $gcd$ of exponents of $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $u$, where $w = u^n$ and $u$ is a non power word. They took pro-p completion of $F_2$ with respect to the prime $p$ and they proved that $u$ is a test element. Hence $w$ is a test element.
I want to know test words in profinite completion of $F_2$. I am wondering if it can be said that $w$ is a test word in $F_2$ if and only if $w$ is a test word in profinite completion of $F_2$. Or we can say this for some class of words, say for the set $[F_2,F_2] \setminus \{e\}$ where every word is a test word in pro-p completion of $F_2$ for every prime $p$.

Shouldnt according to the gcd criterion $x_1$ be a test word in $F_2$, but there is the endomorphism sending $x_1$ to itself and  $x_2$ to its square?

Exponents of $x_1$ and $x_2$ in word $x_1$ are 1 and 0 respectively. The gcd of 1 and 0 is 1. Hence, $x_1$ is not a test word.

Thanks. I overread the word 'not'.
